# Is there a convenient way to identify higher-level buildings?

Tags: cities-skylines

Do I have to learn how they look or is there some graphical indication? (apart from the actual moment when they level up)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the info view in the top left corner (you may already have it open),  the button that has a green house with a star in the middle of it will display buildings in different shades based on their level.